# C# split cookies in httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm having an issue with a connection to HP ALM API. It apparently requires that cookies are written in separate cookie headers. And HttpWebRequest doesnt allow me to do so.

What i have :

```
GET address HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Cookie: Cookie1,Cookie2
Host: mydomain.com
```

What i need :

```
GET address HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Cookie: Cookie1
Cookie: Cookie2
Host: mydomain.com
```

Is there any way to do this ? Sounds like RFC prohibits to merge all values altogether as it is done by WCF HttpWebRequest.

RFC = 6265

Thanks

Thibaud